# How to change interval of an axis in a graph in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, plot, graph, matlab-figure, axes

I want to plot a `semilogy` graph, and for that purpose I have something like this:

```
figure 
semilogy(data_1(:,1), data_1(:,2), 'sb-', 'LineWidth', 2);
hold on
semilogy(data_2(:,1), data_2(:,2), 'mp-', 'LineWidth', 2);
grid on
axis([0 20 10^-4 10^0])
axis([0 20 10^-4 10^0])
```

This works all find and plots things, but the `x-axis` has interval of 5. What I mean is that values in the `x-axis` are labeled as `0, 5, 10, 15, 20`, whereas I want them to have interval of 2, meaning to be labeled as `0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20`. On the other hand, `y-axis` works fine, and it goes as `10^-0, 10^-1, 10^-2, 10^-3, 10^-4`, which is exactly what I want. How can I change the interval on just the `x-axis`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following line after plotting:

```
set(gca,'XTick', 0:2:20);
```